# p-datatable primeng dynamically add and remove rows with reactive forms angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I am looking for example for p-datatable which have an option for add row dynamically and have inline delete option for the row itself to delete the row.

I have searched a couple of links but haven't found the exact solution.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4.3.0/#/datatable/crud

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primengdatatable-curd

I am looking for some design like this

1. two inputs
2. add a button to add a row( will add 2 input and delete button)
3. delete button on a row
4. save button to save data
5. Reactive form
6. patch values after save.

[image]